# Laravel passport - CreateFreshApiToken no laravel_token cookie

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-passport

CreateFreshApiToken, once added to 'web' middleware group in Kernel.php, is supposed to attach laravel_token cookie to response for every request coming through web middleware, isn't it? Eg anything in this group supposed to receive the cookie:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('/{vue?}', function () { return view('index'); } )->where('vue', '[\/\w\.-]*');
});
```

I'm trying to replace current workflow that uses client_secret, seeing that oauth2 and website are on the same domain, the idea of self-consuming api with the help of CreateFreshApiToken had a nice ring to it, though at this point I'm not sure if I'm doing it right.

Comment: The user needs to be logged in once using the traditional way for the middleware to create the cookie.

Comment: @Sandeesh but what happens once I receive the token, how do I authorize user by passing login/password?

Comment: You will not receive the token in this method. The cookie created will contain the encrypted token and will be used by the passport token guard to authenticate requests coming with the cookie. So the routes protected by the `auth:api` middleware will get authenticated without manually attaching any access token. So after the initial login (which should be the traditional way) you need to reload the page at least once so that the cookie gets created by the `CreateFreshApiToken` middleware.

Comment: Hm, so in context of spa I'd have to send dummy get request to receive the token, or tweak CreateFreshApiToken so I'd get it with post response immediately after login?.. I guess I'll stick to oauth2 way then. Thanks Sandeesh, please copy-paste the message into answer box, so I can give you some credit.

Comment: @bruddah I've stucked with the same problem. I have a SPA and I want to use Cookies. LocalStorage isn't as safe as `HttpOnly` `Secure` Cookies are. Get token from `oauth/token` was pretty easy.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Quoting my comment as requested

"You will not receive the token in this method. The cookie created will contain the encrypted token and will be used by the passport token guard to authenticate requests coming with the cookie. So the routes protected by the `auth:api` middleware will get authenticated without manually attaching any access token. So after the initial login (which should be the traditional way) you need to reload the page at least once so that the cookie gets created by the `CreateFreshApiToken` middleware."

Apart from that you can use the password grant for your SPA. This is what you would see 90% of the tutorials on the net do. But they store the client id and secret in the JavaScript file, which is very bad practise from a security perspective. To overcome this you can create a proxy route/middleware which injects the client id and secret. So you would just need to pass the email and password to obtain the access token and refresh token.

But again you need to store the access token and refresh token in the browser's local storage, which is what developers normally do. But the token becomes vulnerable to XSS attacks. So there are lot of angles to think about from a security perspective when working with SPA authentication.

To overcome all the above issues you need to store the token securely in a HttpOnly cookie and then use a middleware to resolve the token from the cookie and authenticate the user on any API request. This is the most practical and secure way of doing authentication with SPA. Laravel Passport does just that but needs some initial work with custom login routes to make it happen. The lack of proper documentation and clarity on it's usage and working is a problem with Passport.

Here are some good resources on these
https://web.archive.org/web/20141208132104/http://alexbilbie.com/2014/11/oauth-and-javascript/

http://esbenp.github.io/2017/03/19/modern-rest-api-laravel-part-4/

https://stormpath.com/blog/token-auth-spa

Comment: Thanks again. I agree, it's a bit tough to find info on passport issues. By the way, do you know how to get oauth2 access token, that's been issued to the current user, from laravel controller? The thing is - I'm currently building an app that uses node server to push notifications to client, and I need to validate the user for node-server somehow - decided accessToken is the easiest way - 1) passing it to the server and saving it as a socket field 2) in controller publish data WITH accessToken to node server, the token in socket will be compared to the one data coming from laravel. Thoughts?

Comment: The `stormpath.com` page has lost all of its content.

The `esbenp.github.io` page starts off very informative. But because the author is using his own framework and assumes his reader has read and followed parts 1-3, his code examples aren't very helpful.